# MongoDB run commands on a specific secondary node

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, replicaset

I want to `db.runCommand` on a secondary node of a replica set, but not the primary [(example)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/compact/#replica-sets).

What connection string should I use in `mongosh` to connect to it?

Connecting to the replica set (e.g. `mongosh mongodb+srv://example.mongodb.net/`) points me to the primary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a direct connection is required, i.e.

```
mongosh "mongodb://example-shard-00-02.web.mongodb.net:27017" \
   --tls \
   --authenticationDatabase admin \
   --username <user> --password <pwd>
```

Comment: if you need particular this node, then yes, `directConnection` is the only option, if you need just any secondary, then better to use `readPreference=Secondary`: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/

Comment: Yes, I'd need a _specific_ node, since I'll have to idempotently operate on each secondary. I cannot run the risk to connect twice to one of the secondaries and never to the other.

Comment: it's quite strange goal, you should remember that there is no guaranties that a node you're connecting to is alive.